# How to set conditional statement for setting a class attribute in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to call a class in a build widget. `number` is an integer variable. My class is `ExpandableContainer` and it has several attributes. One of them is `expandedHeight` and I want to if `number` is smaller than 4, `expandedHeight: 58.0 * number` and otherwise `expandedHeight: 58.0 * 4`.

```
new ExpandableContainer(

              expandedHeight: 58.0*number,
              .
              .
              .
              )
.
.
.

class ExpandableContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool expanded;
  final double expandedHeight;
  final Widget child;

  ExpandableContainer({
    @required this.child,
    this.expandedHeight,
    this.expanded = true,
  });
.
.
.
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary if makes this easy

```
expandedHeight: 58 * (number < 4 ? number : 4),
```